# Find the blank cell in column and paste data in blank cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in some files, i wants to copy all files header in new workbook new sheet in one column.All files are kept in a folder.
e.g. 
i have files, 
File1: Column1,2,3,4,5 are headers like this i have multiple files.

Column1:Name  Column2:Surname   Column3:Email  Column4:MobNo    Column5:Address

as the result( all files header )is copied in new sheet as

```
    Column B
     Name
    Surname
    Email
    MobNo
   Address
   Blank Cell
```

i wants to copy file2 headers to next balnk cell in same columnB(i.e. file2 haders copy from Blank cell and so on
i am not getting idea to code

Thanks for answer...!!!!

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem? Could you show us some code if you have tried to write? Or may be any idea how you want to go to solve this?

Comment: first i wants to read header from first file and before paste, first check blank cell in column B (this column B is new sheet where i am going store all files headers ) and do all this in for loop.

Comment: all files headers are copied to Column B . This is my Idea

Comment: will u plz help me..... Tanks in advance

Comment: I'd really suggest re-working the question. It looks like you have a directory with multiple files and you want to open each file and extract the column headers, but I could be wrong..

Comment: simply i wants to copy all headers from each file (these are closed files) to new sheet in column

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I assume you are searching for blank rows in `Sheet1` and then copying headers (first row) from `Sheet2` into the blank row found in `Sheet1`:

```
Sub find_next_blank_row()

    Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
    Dim blank_cell As Long

    Set search_result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find("")

    If Not search_result Is Nothing Then
        blank_cell = search_result.Row

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(blank_cell).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: but i wants to copy all headers in new sheet as column. ater one file next file headers should paste below first file by finding blank cell or other method. Like this all files headers should copy & paste in one column only.

Comment: and i am reading headers from multiple files that are kept in one folder.

Comment: i think first open file ,read headers and then find blank cell in new sheet in columnB & paste it as column  and we iterate this .

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim mainwb As Workbook
'Dim wb As Workbook


----------


----------


=======

 Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
    Dim blank_cell As Long


Path = "C:\Test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    'MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
    'Set sh = MySheet()
   'Variable = ActiveSheet.Name
  ' Sheets(Variable).Range("A1:D1").Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet2").Column(B2).Select.Activate.Paste
   ' Sheets("Sheet2").Active
    'Columns("B2").Select

  Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
  Variable = ActiveSheet.Name
  wbk.Sheets(Variable).Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy

   Workbooks("DFT Tool.xlsm").Activate
'Activate Worksheet
Workbooks("DFT Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

' ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Columns("E").Select
    Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```